# How can I specify which paragraph styles should be part of the TOC in MS Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, table-of-contents

I've written a book of about 300 pages, and I'd like to generate a TOC (table of contents) for it. All the information I can find on the web tells me how to do this based on the built-in paragraph style names Heading1, Heading2, etc. These names are meaningless for my document, however, so I wrote it using paragraph names that makes sense for what I'm doing, e.g., "Unnumbered Chapter", "Chapter", "Guideline", etc. I've also assigned Outline levels to these styles so that they are organized correctly in the Navigation Pane.

I'd assumed that to generate a TOC, all I'd have to do would be to tell Word which paragraph styles to include, and it would use the outline levels I'd already assigned to structure the TOC.  But at this point, I can't even figure out how to tell Word which paragraph styles correspond to text that should be in the TOC.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're on the right track.

From the ribbon, select:

> References/Table of Contents/Insert Table of Contents

On the dialog that appears, click

> Options...

The presented dialog will have an (already checked by default) option to:

> 'Build table of contents from: Styles

(as well as Outline levels and Table entry fields).  Ensure the Styles option is checked.

Next proceed through the list of available styles and check any that you wish to be tabulated.  Go through the whole list as I've seen Word choose to set ToC entries for Paragraph headings when it chooses the Styles to include.